# How to attach profile type to specific user role?

Tags: 7, users

I have multiple profile types and multiple user roles.  I want to combine specific profile types with users of specific roles.  For example, customer roles have their own profiles, content authors have their own profiles, etc.

Is there a way to assign them together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do this with permissions.